# Determining the classification of languages

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, halting-problem

> $L_0 = \{ \langle M, w, 0 \rangle \mid \text{$M$ halts on $w$}\}$ 
>   $L_1 = \{ \langle M, w, 1 \rangle \mid \text{$M$ does not halt on  $w$}\}$
>
> $L = L_0 \cup L_1$

I need to determine where in the hierarchy of languages (recursive, recursively enumerable, not recursively enumerable) $L$ and its complement $\overline L$ belong. I reasoned as follows

$L = \{ \langle M, w, x\rangle  \mid \text{$M$ halts on $w$ when $x=0$, $M$ doesn't halt on $w$ when $x = 1$, $x \in \{0, 1\}$}\}$

$L$ is clearly not recursively enumerable as a Turing machine wouldn't be able accept in all cases.  It can accept only in case the input refers to $L_0$, but can't in case the input refers to $L_1$.

$\overline L = \overline L_0 \cap \overline L_1 = \emptyset$
Thus $\overline L$ is recursive.

Is my reasoning ok? This is a question from a previous exam paper.

Comment: You have a mistake in the computation of $\overline{L}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two hints

1. If $\bar L$ would be decidable (recursive), then so would be $L$, and you just argued that $L$ is not even recursively enumerable. Maybe you have a closer look on what $\bar L_0 \cap \bar L_1$ really is. For example
   $\bar L_0 = \{ \langle M, w, 0 \rangle \mid \text{$M$ does not halts on $w$}\} \cup \{ \langle M, w, x \rangle \mid x\not=0\} $.
2. If you want to argue formally correct that a language is not recursively enumerable, or decidable, then try to use a reduction, for example the [many one reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction). Reduce  a a problem, whose status you know, to $L$ and you can say something about $L$.

Comment: I am thinking out aloud here. L is representative of the question, does a Turing machine accept/reject(halt) or loop around infinitely(not-halt) on an input string? $\overline L = \overline L_0 \cap \overline L_1$ has to represent, does a Turing machine halt and not halt simultaneously on an input string?  The answer is a clear no. Thus $\overline L$ has to be decidable/recursive. I realise that the conclusion is wrong(If $\overline L$ would be decidable (recursive), then so would be L, and you just argued that L is not even recursively enumerable), but I can't seem to see the flaw.

Comment: @AbhijithMadhav: I extended hint 1 slightly

Comment: Is your edit correct? Did you mean to say, $\bar L_0 = \{ \langle M, w, 0 \rangle \mid \text{$M$ does NOT halt on $w$}\} \cup \{ \langle M, w, x \rangle \mid x\not=0\} $

Comment: @AbhijithMadhav yes you were correct. That was a typo.

Comment: $\bar L_0 \cap \bar L_1 = \{ \langle M, w, 0 \rangle \mid \text {$M$ does not halt on $w$}\} \cup \{ \langle M, w, 1 \rangle \mid \text {$M$ halts on $w$}\}$. Similar to the argument for $L$, $\bar L$ is also not recursively enumerable. I have assumed that the third element of the triplet of each language belongs to {0, 1}. The result won't matter otherwise. Initially, I think I got $\bar L$ wrong as a result of trying to verbalize everything at once. Breaking down things helped. Let me know if I have missed anything this time.

Comment: Depending on the definition of $\langle . \rangle$, $\overline{L_0}$ would also contain all strings that are no encodings of a triplet $(M,w,x)$.

Comment: @Raphael, what do you mean by "definition of $\langle . \rangle$"?

Comment: @AbhijithMadhav: $\langle . \rangle$ is (here) a function that encodes a Turing machine, an input, and a natural number into some string. It is not given explicitly, most likely because coming up with a suitable definition is considered an easy exercise. If you define it to be bijective, the given identity regarding $\overline{L_0}$ is correct; otherwise, there are words missing, namely those outside of the image of $\langle . \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

You can recognize (but not decide) $L_1$ (essentially checking it ends "0", if so simulating $M$ on $x$ by a universal Turing machine $U$, otherwise reject).

$L_2$ is essentially the complement of the language of $U$, which is not recognizable.

$L$ is not recognizable. If it was, say by a Turing machine $R$, you could run $R$ in parallel over $\langle M, w, 0 \rangle$ and $\langle M, w, 1 \rangle$. The one that accepts tells you if $M$ accepts $w$, which is impossible to do in general.